# bash variable expansion in if statement

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, substitution

Checking for the existence of a directory which should resolve to ~/code/devtools/deploy-mix.

This if statement doesn't pass -- though I can `cd ~/code/devtools/deploy-mix`.  Plz help with bash syntax  :)

```
GIT_DIR="$HOME/code"
if [ -d "${GIT_DIR}/devtools/deploy-mix" ]; then
    echo "found $GIT_DIR/devtools/deploy-mix"
fi
```

output:

```
sh -x script
```

'[' -d '$HOME/code/devtools/deploy-mix' ']'

I'd love to give out some internet karma for this one and I'm ok if you decide to call me a noob (sometimes the coding angle doesn't sit on your shoulder).

Comment: Has nothing to do with the `if` at all. You'd have the exact same problem running `test -d "$GIT_DIR"; echo $?`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `~` by `$HOME` or remove quotes.

Examples:

```
GIT_DIR="$HOME/code"
GIT_DIR=~/'code'
```

Comment: Might be worth being more clear about *which* quotes to remove. The `GIT_DIR='~/code'` quotes are bad; the `[ -d "${GIT_DIR}" ]` quotes are good.

Comment: GIT_DIR="$HOME/code"
if [ -d "${GIT_DIR}/devtools/deploy-mix" ]; then
 echo "found $GIT_DIR/devtools/deploy-mix"
fi

sh -x 
'[' -d '$HOME/code/devtools/deploy-mix' ']'